# Is value in a string stored in table

Tags: mysql

I have a table t1 with several columns. One of them contains a string of numeric values, and can be a single number, like **14** or be comma separated, like **3, 14, 66, 1884**

I need to run a query to check if a given number is in that column. I thought I'll use "IN", but I don't think it'll be the right approach. For some reason having a brain-freeze, possibly because it's been a loooooong day and caffeine all wore out...

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ".$myValue." IN (t1.myStr) ...?
```

Comment: there must be some mysql string split function somewhere you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** function.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, myStr)
```